# Angular 1 or Angular 2 going forward

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, angular, frontend

I don't think this is an easy question to answer but I am unable to find a comparison of the use cases for angular 1 and 2 rather than simply listing the new features. At my work we develop client side only web apps, we are not allowed to use a server, all of our content is loaded and delivered through iPads, and our development team is small and (relatively) inexperienced. We are just wrapping up an angular 1 project and are about to start a new project that is based on this recently finished one, it will be however much larger in scope and functionality. Because of this we thought it might be a good time to transition since we have already figured out the basic logic and structure of how this larger project will work. So I guess the best way to break it down is as follows:

- are there any benefits (over angular 1) to angular 2, excluding features that depend on a server?
- are there types of applications that angular 2 is better suited for?
- does the community at large view angular 1 and 2 as coexisting with both being developed and supported or is it going to be angular 2 going forward?
- am I looking at this completely wrong and it's not an all out nothing approach and we can develop in both?

Any advice is appreciated, if this is on the wrong section let me know and I will move it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any question that you should be moving into Angular 2. Especially now that Angular 2 has reached the stage of Release Candidate. If not migrating from 1 to 2, then starting your new project completely in Angular 2.

Angular 2 is a completely new framework and, in my opinion, much easier and simplified.  There are a whole array of reasons why Angular 2 is better than Angular 1, not the least of which is that Angular 2 is *much* faster and is the future as far as Angular development is concerned.

Yes there are some growing pains, but I firmly believe you will be very happy with Angular 2 and not look back.  Take the time to learn it and you will be very happy you did.